# Having issues with apostrophes in strings (Scala)

Tags: java, scala

I'm running into some weird issues in Scala right now. I'm writing a spell checker and the dictionary is in a .txt file that is being read in and stored in a map. In my dictionary is the word "Boston's". I did a check to see if "Boston's" was in the map by using the contains method and it's there. However, the real issue arises when I do the spell check on a document.

"Boston's" is being read in from the document I'm spell checking and stored in a ListBuffer, but when I check if my "dictionary" map contains it, it says it doesn't. So I did a println on both instances of "Boston's" (in my "dictionary" map and in my "wordToBeChecked" list) and I noticed something odd:

Both are there, but they look different. The one in my wordToBeChecked list looks as if it contains a single quote rather than an apostrophe. I've been trying to fix this for hours, but now I'm officially stumped.

Comment: The character you can enter directly from your keyboard (') is often used as an apostophe but the "nice looking" apostrophy (’) is a different character, and the backtick (`) is yet another one. Note that many word processors will replace the "keyboard apostrophy" with the "pretty apostrophy" as you type. So perhaps you have one form in your file and another one in the document you're checking. It would be best if you could copy both via the clipboard and paste them here for comparison. They may look very similar on screen but reveal to be different codes if you just dump the byte values.

Comment: That actually seems to be the issue. When I copy Boston's from the dictionary, it works. Now, my issue is getting everything in the same encoding. I tried copying and pasting the dictionary and saving it in a .txt and now I get this: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException.     How should I deal with these encoding problems?

Comment: @jtabone16 The text editor was saving the file in a different encoding than the process reading the file later. Make sure both use the same encoding. For the text editor, this depends on the product you use of course. For Java, the various classes that read characters from files (like `InputStreamReader`, for example), have an optional `charset` parameter. That's where you pass in the encoding. The `Charset` class also offers constants for commonly used encodings. Usually, UTF-8 is a good choice. Unless you need to use some very exotic characters.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe is a good read.

Comment: @Madoc Should I be using a certain text editor? I tried using UTF-8 when I called fromFile and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @jtabone16 Every editor that lets you choose (or at least see) the charset is fine. Personally, I use Sublime Text (only available for Mac). Sublime offers the menu option "File > Save with Encoding > ...". Other editors can be similar. Another popular Mac text editor is Text Mate. On Windows systems, Ultra Edit is a good choice. Beyond text editors, a programming IDE usually offers an encoding choice for plain text files. For example, IntelliJ Idea shows the charset in the lower right corner and allows you to change it there as well.